# Disable approval required consent in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

When an end-user is accessing their organization data by using my Azure OAuth APP, they are being asked for admin approval, the consent shows the message as "Approval Required", Can anyone will help me out on how to solve this issue so that end-user will not be asked for the admin approval?

Authorization URL we used to authenticate the end-user:- [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&state={{state}}&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}&client_id={{client_id}}&resource={{resource}}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&state=%7B%7Bstate%7D%7D&redirect_uri=%7B%7Bredirect_uri%7D%7D&client_id=%7B%7Bclient_id%7D%7D&resource=%7B%7Bresource%7D%7D)

[Admin Consent Image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgZgJ.png

Answer (score 0):

From your application's perspective, you cannot do anything to stop this prompt to appear.

Following are some of the reasons why your users are seeing this prompt:

- Your application is asking for some tenant-wide permissions that only an admin can consent to.
- The admin has set a policy in Azure AD which blocks users to consent to 3rd party applications like yours.

Only solution to this is to have an admin in the target Azure AD to consent to the application. They can do it by several means:

- Manually by logging in into your application (like your users) and consenting to the application.
- Granting admin consent to the application by logging in into Azure Portal and then visiting the application's page in Enterprise Applications section.
- Visiting the admin consent URL specific for your application.

To learn more, please see this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent.