# Azure SSO- How to remove approval required screen after sign in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to add Azure AD auth for my custom SPA. I have registered the app in the app registration in the Azure portal.

When I call this "APP" using APIs I am able to get the login screen and MFA but after logging in to the Azure account I am getting Approval required screen and I want to get rid of this, what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of Approval required screen after signing in, user settings of your app have to be changed. Only the admin with `Global Administrator` role of the tenant can do that. So, make sure to have that role.

Note the `client_id` of your app that can be found in your Overview tab.

[image: 1]

Create an `adminconsent` URL like this:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=your_client_id

Now, access this URL in the browser and it asks you to pick the azure account.

Select the account with `Global Administrator` role.

[image: 2]

Now, a **consent prompt** will appear where you have to accept the permissions.

[image: 4]

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> User Settings -> Admin Consent Requests.**
**Set ‘Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to’ to “No”***

[image: 4]

By this, when the user tried to access the application using authorization API, they won’t get ‘Approval Required’ page anymore that disables all future admin consent operations.

For more information, go through below links.

**References:**

[Disable approval required consent in Azure - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/586661/disable-approval-required-consent-in-azure.html)

[Disable approval required consent in Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534595/disable-approval-required-consent-in-azure)