# iOS authentication with Azure AD

Tags: c#, ios, swift, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have an iOS app that connect to Azure AD for authentication. We use MSAL library in iOS app to call the azure AD. We are facing some issue when trying to authenticate. The error says that we need to configure the app registration to support multi tenant application. The error is confusing because we only have one tenant in our Azure AD.

[image]

If we add the tenant it will ask for Approval. Why it's asking for approval? how can we remove that approval?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4frw.png)

Comment: As the error message says, you either need to use a multi tenant application or use a tenant specific authentication url. You can pass a your tenant specific authority https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/Classes/MSALAuthority.html#/c:objc(cs)MSALAuthority(cm)authorityWithURL:error: Via the config parameter

Comment: We tried that but it is asking for a approval after login

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4frw.png

Comment: Your app is asking for scopes that require admin approval. You need to get an admin to approve your app in the Azure AD portal.

Comment: Once we approve the app is that applicable to all the user that will use the App? Will all the users that needs the app goes to that approval process?

Comment: No, once an admin approves the app it is approved for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check the authorization URL you are currently using to sign-in your application.**

- If it is somewhat like below, only users from that tenant will be able to log in.
  **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>`**
- If this tenant Id corresponds to one of your organizations where you manage users, you can grant admin consent to that tenant in **Azure portal** like below:

***Go to Azure portal -> Azure Active directory -> Your application -> API permissions -> Add required permissions -> Grant admin consent.***

- **Otherwise**, you should either replace this with the tenant Id of that tenant or with '**common**' which allows users from any tenant to sign in like this: **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`**
- If not, users from other tenant gets this approval page.
- An administrator must provide ***Admin Consent*** in the case where access is required to more sensitive resources, or at a broader scope.
- Granting tenant-wide admin consent requires you to sign in as a **Global Administrator**, an **Application Administrator**, or a **Cloud Application Administrator.**

If you want to remove that admin consent screen,

***Go to Azure portal -> Azure Active directory -> Enterprise Applications -> Consent and permissions -> User Consent Settings***

[image]

To know more in detail, please find below **links** if they are helpful.

**References:**

[Azure SSO- How to remove approval required screen after sign in - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237885/azure-sso-how-to-remove-approval-required-screen-after-sign-in/71250095#71250095)

[How to fix the ‘Need admin approval’ error while trying to sign in to the signature management app (codetwo.com)](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/resolving-need-admin-approval-error/)

[Exchange Online: Apple Internet Accounts - Need admin approval | diecknet](https://diecknet.de/en/2020/05/10/Apple-Internet-Accounts-Office365/)

Comment: We are able to successfully login but when we use the bearer token it returns 401 unauthorize