# Azure AD restrict users to login if not assigned to aplication without user assignement

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, msal-react

We want to use Azure AD as the authentication mechanism for our project. To do that, in our organization Azure AD, i have registered an application for our project, added the SPA redirect URI. Added the internal users into the same enterprise application by using Add Users/Groups. Since the frontend app is based on React, we are using @azure/msal-react for authentication and using org AD tenatid and the respective clientid in authConfig.js file with scope as User.Read. Here i am using loginRedirect to start the login process on load of application.

As we are using org Azure AD, there are other applications as well created by other developers. I want to restrict login of other internal users to access this application. I was trying to use **User Assignment required as Yes** to achieve that, but in that case it is asking for "Need Admin Approval" which we don't want. As for big organization, Global Admin/Application Admin/Cloud Admin will be in different timezone and user shouldn't wait to get the approval from them.

So is there any way i can restrict other internal users to access the application and show them  unauthorized page when trying to access the application. Only allocated users would be able to login to the application.

Please suggest. If you need anymore info, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**To get rid of **"*Need Admin Approval*"** screen, please follow below steps:**

- Make sure you have **"Global Admin Role"** to change user settings in Azure active directory.
- ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Go to Enterprise Applications -> Click on User Settings -> Admin Consent Requests.**  **Set ‘Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to’ to “No”***.

[image]

- Make sure to **Grant admin consent** for the required api permissions you added to your application.

[image: image2]

- After granting it, it should be like below:

[image: image3]

***I have tried in my environment, I was able to login to the application without waiting for Admin approval.***

**AFAIK**, to restrict other internal users to access the application and show them unauthorized page when trying to access the application try making use of **conditional access policies.**

To know how to do that in detail, Make use of below **references**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access#create-a-conditional-access-policy

[c# - iOS authentication with Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71848550/ios-authentication-with-azure-ad/71855752#71855752).

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response. I don't have Global Admin role. Admin consent request is already No for our org Azure AD and we can't change it. Also conditional access policies is disabled for us as User. Right now the main problem is if i am registering an application in our org level Azure AD and adding some internal users/groups in it, then other internal users are able to pass through the authentication as thy are part of same Azure AD. Wanted to show unauthorized access to those not assigned users for it without User assignment required and conditional access policies. Please suggest.