# The offline scope is automatically added in the Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: reactjs, azure, msal.js

I have developed an app where users can log in with their Microsoft account using MSAL.js. The problem is that when users try to log in with a work account, they are prompted for administrator approval. This issue occurs even though I did not include the offline_access scope in the authentication request , but I believe it is added automatically. Is there something that needs to be adjusted in Azure? Is there a way to avoid this permission request?

Comment: Did you get your answer? I'm having the same issue

Comment: my problem was  in setting up our Azure

Answer (score 0):

> While signing in, user will get **"Approval required"** screen if they
> include **Delegated** permissions in authentication request.

I registered one Azure AD application that have **`User.Read`** permission added like below:

[image]

When the user tried to login with Azure AD account using below authentication request, got same screen saying **"Approval required"** like this:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=appID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= User.Read
&state=1234
```

[image]

> To avoid this permission request, you need to grant admin consent to those **Delegated** permissions by signing in with **Global Administrator** account.

In my case, I ran below admin consent URL in browser and selected  **Global Administrator** account to sign in:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/adminconsent?client_id=appID
```

[image]

Now, click on **`Accept`** to grant **admin consent** for requested permissions like this:

[image]

When I tried to sign in again with demo user account now, I did n't get **"Approval required"** screen and able to login successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure SSO- How to remove approval required screen after sign in - Stack Overflow by **me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237885/azure-sso-how-to-remove-approval-required-screen-after-sign-in)